# HttpClient Task canceled - Thread Safety

Tags: c#, .net, http, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a WebSocket that sends me events rapidly whenever there is a new message available, the event call for this looks like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _onStringMessage(e.RawData));
```

```
public async void _onStringMessage(var eventSent)
{
    ... // business logic
    var variable = await _httpClient.getAsync(eventSent.Url);
    ... // business logic
    var success = await _httpClient.postAsync(eventSent.Url + "/arg");
    ... // business logic
}
```

This code runs fine for a few iterations and then get a "Task was cancelled" exception error on either the GET or the POST request. The _httpClient is a standard .NET HttpClient wrapped in a IHttpClient class declared as a class variable. However, if I add a Semiphore like below, everything runs perfect:

```
public async void _onStringMessage(var eventSent)
{
    await semiphore.WaitAsync();

    ... // business logic
    var variable = await _httpClient.getAsync(eventSent.Url);
    ... // business logic
    var success = await _httpClient.postAsync(eventSent.Url + "/arg");
    ... // business logic

    semiphore.Release();
}
```

I am using .NET 4.6.1 and as far as I understood, both of these HTTP methods should be thread safe. Both methods ends up in a SendAsync method via the HTTP handler but that should also be thread safe. So I do not understand why I get the Task was cancelled exception? The only thing I can think of is that the server rejects the calls because too many requests at the same time, but then I imagine I would get some other error, like HTTP BadRequest or similar. This method runs approximately 10-20 times per second. My timeout is set to 1 second and all request are so far only on localhost.

Comment: Not related to the problem but will it always run on localhost. Because if just that part does 20 calls a seconds that web server in order to process in under 1 second you will need some serious computer / internet connection.

Comment: TaskCanceledException with a HttpClient usually indicates a timeout

Comment: It will not always run on localhost. Yes it is many requests, but with the semiphore it can handle it. But I do not want to use the semiphore because it is not supposed to be needed.

Comment: Well, from the information you're giving, it seems pretty obvious that requests are piling up faster than they can be handled, and end up in timeout. The only question is whether the client or the server is the bottleneck. On client-side, you may be hitting the limit in number of connection per host, you can try changing it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netframework-4.8 . Otherwise you'll have to setup some kind of throttling, like the semaphore

Comment: Can I somehow determine that? I also do not understand how the Semiphore actually helps here. Could you elaborate on that? It simply slows down the requests?